# How can I make a class diagram for searching a video?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

Suppose I have a website where cat videos are uploaded. Each video has a name/title.

Now, a user can search for a video by entering the name of the video into the search bar. When a user clicks search, all the video titles' that contain the search term are displayed.

How would my class diagram look like for the user searching for a video?

Comment: We're not here to solve your design. Go visit a class.

Comment: please mark an answer as accepted if it helps you the most.

Answer (score 1):

You should start off with other videos such as Activity or Sequence diagrams: They should outline more detailed requirements. From that, you can derive a class diagram, because it will propose a concept which you can only do if you know about the requirements that you have to fulfill.

Answer (score 0):

You are elaborating a use case. I think the best way to reflect this scenario in UML is to use a small use case diagram with a use case detailed description. If there are several requests/messages going here and there between components, you can even consider using an activity diagram or/and sequence diagram for a more detailed representation on the implementation.

To get the right design decisions, you will need a little bit of understanding on the options that the UML provides us to elaborate a software design. Therefore, refer 4+1 View Model Architecture with the respective diagrams to have a clear idea on the topic.

***4+1 Views with appropriate diagrams***
[image: 4+1 Views with appropriate diagrams]

*Image Source: https://wiki.cantara.no/download/attachments/16515232/4_pluss_1_view_of_sw_architecture.PNG?version=1&modificationDate=1233598232398*